# Adapter do RecyclerView: problema ao mudar a cor de um botão

Tags: android, android-adapter

Estou usando `RecyclerView` e montando uma lista com vários `buttons`. Consigo mudar a cor do `button` de acordo com um `if`, se a condição for verdadeira ele muda, porém ao subir e descer a lista, acaba mudando outros `buttons` que não podem mudar a cor.

Adapter

```
public class RVAdapterTp1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterTp1.MyViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<horario> horarioI;
private ArrayList<horario> horarioO;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private MaterialDialog mMaterialDialog;
private Context mContext;

public RVAdapterTp1(Context c, ArrayList<horario> i, ArrayList<horario> o) {
    this.horarioI = i;
    this.horarioO = o;
    mContext = c;
    //mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tp1_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder mvh = new MyViewHolder((v));
    return mvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (position < horarioO.size()) {
        holder.cvO.setText(horarioO.get(position).getIo());
        holder.cvO.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (horarioO.get(position).getOb() == 0) {
            holder.cvO.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC107"));
           holder.cvO.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mMaterialDialog = new MaterialDialog(mContext);
                    mMaterialDialog.setTitle("ATENÇÃO");
                    mMaterialDialog.setMessage(horarioO.get(position).getObs());
                    mMaterialDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mMaterialDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    mMaterialDialog.show();
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        holder.cvO.setText("");
        holder.cvO.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    if (position < horarioI.size()) {
        holder.cvI.setText(horarioI.get(position).getIo());
        holder.cvI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.v("AQUIIIaaaaaa", holder.cvI.getText().toString());

        if (horarioI.get(position).getOb() == 0) {
            horarioI.get(position).setOb(1);
            Log.v("AQUIII", holder.cvI.getText().toString());
            holder.cvI.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC107"));
            Log.v("AQUIIIeeeee", horarioI.get(position).getIo());
            holder.cvI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mMaterialDialog = new MaterialDialog(mContext);
                    mMaterialDialog.setTitle("ATENÇÃO");
                    mMaterialDialog.setMessage(horarioI.get(position).getObs());
                    mMaterialDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mMaterialDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    Log.v("AQUIIIuuuu", holder.cvI.getText().toString());
                    mMaterialDialog.show();
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        holder.cvI.setText("");
        holder.cvI.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (horarioO.size() >= horarioI.size()) {
        return horarioO.size();
    } else {
        return horarioI.size();
    }
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public Button cvI;
    public Button cvO;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cvI = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvI);
        cvO = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvO);
    }
}
}
```

Fragmento

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tp1, container, false);


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_list);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    adapterTp1 = new RVAdapterTp1(getActivity(), horarioI, horarioO);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterTp1);

    return view;

}
```

Layout do item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llTp1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cvI"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"></Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cvO"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout RecyclerView

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Frags.Tp1Frag">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/rv_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Layout do viewPager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextColor="#B6B6B6"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF"/>
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

O RecyclerView é uma versão otimizada de um ListView por um motivo: como o nome diz, ele reaproveita os Views. Quando você muda a cor do botão de um item que está em um View, pode acontecer de quando outro item for exibido neste mesmo View ele não recarregar o botão e ele ficar com a cor trocada.

Tente mudar a cor do botão para cor original no início da onBindViewHolder( ).

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( final MyViewHolder holder, final int position)   
{

    holder.cvO.setBackgroundColor( COR ORIGINAL );
    holder.cvI.setBackgroundColor( COR ORIGINAL );
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa pegar o id do item selecionado no metodo onCreateViewHolder aí sim realizar a determinada ação

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.stop_item_list, parent, false);

    botão.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) { 
           // ação de troca de cor!

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver usando holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

Comment: Você não resolveu, apenas contornou o problema.